# NSURL not getting allocatd with NSString

Tags: iphone, nsurl

This' strange because all my other NSUrls in program are working properly but this one isn't getting allocated with NSString. I'm using:

```
urlStr_ = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.10.2/justmeans/trunk/appaddgoodwork?gencode=%@&deviceid=@%@&sessionkey=%@&userid=%@&updatetext=%@&companyid=%d&service_type=%@",securitycode,deviceId,sessionKey,userId,finalTextInTxtVw,companyId,service_type];
urlStr_ = [urlStr_ stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)NSUTF8StringEncoding];

url_ = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlStr_];
```

What are the possible reasons for NSUrl not getting allocated? Can anybody please help?

Thanx in advance.

P.S. NSString is not empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string seems to not be correctly formatted. See the `%@&deviceid=@%@&sessionkey` part; should not it be `%@&deviceid=%@&sessionkey`?

Comment: Oh my God... Thanx for pointing out.. This' weird on my part.. Thanx for your help..

Answer (score 1):

Useally it is because the string is not formatted correctly for encoding as an URL. Try to chop of bits of the string to find the offending part.

Comment: Thanx Claus for replying.. But what do you mean by "Try to chop of bits of the string to find the offending part". I tried looking wheather the string isn't containing spaces and found out that it's not. I'm really confused.