# NSURL and NSString converting issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring, nsurl

When trying to load a request I do like this:

```
NSString *urlStrings = [NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"kPicturesURL", @"urls", nil) stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Articles/a.pdf"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStrings];
```

Inside of "urls" I have this key:

```
/* Service pictures directory */
"kPicturesURL" = "http://192.168.2.104/myApp/Pictures";
```

And I get this result: (The first line is "urlStrings" and the second is the "url")

```
(NSString *) $6 = 0x092a8f60 http:/192.168.2.104/myApp/Pictures/Articles/a.pdf
2012-11-22 09:18:20.093 NPE[7680:c07] Couldn't issue file extension for path: /192.168.2.104/myApp/Pictures/Articles/a.pdf
```

I've tried those questions:

[NSString and NSUrl not converting properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408551/nsstring-and-nsurl-not-converting-properly)

[NSURL not getting allocatd with NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203842/nsurl-not-getting-allocatd-with-nsstring)

[Pass NSString into NSURL URLWithString ?](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/19174-pass-nsstring-into-nsurl-urlwithstring.html)

[NSString to NSURL ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117066/nsstring-to-nsurl)

[NSString to NSURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456605/nsstring-to-nsurl)

Non of those worked, what seems to be the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: are you trying  :-NSString *myString = [myURL absoluteString];?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

So, using one of the following did worked eventually.

This one:

```
NSString *stringURL = [url absoluteString];
```

Comment: myURL.absoluteString - This one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of:

```
http:/192.168.2.104/myApp/Pictures/Articles/a.pdf
```

This:

```
http://192.168.2.104/myApp/Pictures/Articles/a.pdf
```

Comment: Still the same error: `(NSString *) $5 = 0x096bb580 http://192.168.2.104/myApp/Pictures/Articles/a.pdf` this is the url: 
`2012-11-22 09:39:18.268 NPE[8084:c07] Couldn't issue file extension for path: /myApp/Pictures/Articles/a.pdf`

Comment: Can you try `fileURLWithPath` instead of `URLWithString`

Comment: `2012-11-22 09:48:05.511 NPE[8229:c07] Couldn't issue file extension for path: /http:/www.zen134237.zen.co.uk/A_Gifted_Man_1x01_-_Pilot.pdf` (fileURLWithPath)

Comment: it's a problem with the file extension i.e the .pdf